# Says 'coroutine was never awaited', but await exists in function

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am getting an error message in which it says that I forgot to await a couroutine, which is not true, as highlighted in the code.

This is the function:

```py
def _aio(self, f):
    """ Make some function run asynchronously. """

    async def aio_wrapper(**kwargs):
        f_bound = functools.partial(f, **kwargs)
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        return await loop.run_in_executor(self._executor, f_bound)

    return aio_wrapper
```

Here is me using the code:

```py
for key in image_keys:
    res = self._aio(self._client.get_object)(Bucket=self.bucket_name, Key=key)
    print(type(res))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't `await` the `aio_wrapper`:

```
res = await self._aio(self._client.get_object)(Bucket=self.bucket_name, Key=key)
```

When running `self._aio(self._client.get_object)` your wrapper executes and returns a coroutine function which you have to call and `await`.